# Does data loss happens in fast sender and very slow receiver?

Tags: sockets

I have an application consisting of client and server by making use of sockets.
On the server side in the thread where it is receiving messages from client i have made a sleep call for 10 sec.Now when i send messages from client 1000000 times to server then messages being received from server is very slowly.My question is as follows:

-Does it mean that the receiving call on server side is blocking call?
-Secondly,is there any good document which can make me understand better the blocking and non blocking behavior of send and receive call of sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you're using [TCP or UDP sockets](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/key-differences-between-tcp-and-udp-protocols/).  TCP guarantees delivery, UDP doesn't.  So in a UDP application packets can be dropped for any number of reasons, including if the servers sends too quickly to the client.

By default, calls on sockets are blocking calls.  You have to set non-blocking explicitly.